# Unable to retrieve access token for Moodle on Android phone

Tags: android, angularjs, moodle

I have created an authentication service based on [Jason Watmore's example](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/05/26/angularjs-basic-http-authentication-example), and it works fine in the Ripple emulator for Android, logs in, saves the token to jStorage, and uses it to access other web services.

It was also working in the actual Android phone till yesterday.

I have tested to see if jStorage is working in my Android phone (it is), and I have tried removing all the app's data using the Settings.

Any idea why the Android phone is not fetching the token from the Moodle server (but the emulator *is* fetching it)?

Here's my service:

```
myApp.factory('AuthenticationService',
   ['$http', '$cookies', '$rootScope', '$timeout', '$log',
   function ($http, $cookies, $rootScope, $timeout, $log) {
       var service = {};

       service.Login = function (username, password, callback) {

           //$log.info('Login function called');

           if ((username.length && password.length) && (username !== '' && password != '')) {

               var loginUrl = 'https://my.moodle.url/local/token.php';

               // use $.param jQuery function to serialize data from JSON
               var data = $.param({
                   username: username,
                   password: password,
                   service: 'brookesid_ws'
               });
               //$log.info(data);
               var config = {
                   headers: {
                       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
                   }
               }

               $http.post(loginUrl, data, config)
                       .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                           $log.info(data);
                           myToken = data.token;
                           dataString = JSON.stringify(data);
                           if (dataString.indexOf('error') > 0) {

                               $rootScope.className = 'error';
                               $rootScope.PostDataResponse = 'Invalid user credentials, please try again';
                               $rootScope.isAuthenticated = false;
                               $rootScope.dataLoading = false;
                           }
                           else {
                                $.jStorage.set('session', myToken, { TTL: 28800000 });
                               //$cookies.put('session', myToken);
                           }

                           $rootScope.isAuthenticated = true;
                          // $log.info('isAuthenticated = true');
                           callback(dataString);
                       })
                       .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
                           $rootScope.isAuthenticated = false;
                           $rootScope.ResponseDetails = "data: " + data +
                                   "<br />status: " + status +
                                   "<br />headers: " + header +
                                   "<br />config: " + config;
                           responsedata = JSON.stringify(data);
                           callback(responsedata);
                           $log.info('error: '+responsedata);
                       });
           } else {

               $rootScope.className = 'error';
               $rootScope.isAuthenticated = false;
               $rootScope.PostDataResponse = 'Please enter a username and password';
           }

       };

       service.SetCredentials = function (sessionToken) {

           var JSONObject = JSON.parse(sessionToken);
           var key = 'token';
           myToken = JSONObject[key];
           $log.info('session Token: ' + sessionToken);
           $log.info('myToken: ' + myToken);
           $rootScope.globals = {
               currentUser: {
                   token: myToken
               }
           };

           $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + sessionToken; // jshint ignore:line

           //retrieve last login date and then update it
           $rootScope.lastLogin = $.jStorage.get('lastLogin', '');
           var today = new Date();
           epochToday = Math.round(today.getTime() / 1000);
           $.jStorage.set('lastLogin', epochToday, { TTL: 28800000 });
           //$log.info('Rootscope Last Login: '+$rootScope.lastLogin);

           $.jStorage.set('globals', $rootScope.globals, { TTL: 28800000 });
           $.jStorage.set('session', myToken, { TTL: 28800000 });
           $.jStorage.set('loginStatus', 'logged in', { TTL: 28800000 });

           $log.info('Token (jStorage) ' + $.jStorage.get('session', ''));
           //$log.info('Last login (jStorage) ' + $.jStorage.get('lastLogin', ''));
           //$log.info('Login status (jStorage) ' + $.jStorage.get('loginStatus', ''));
       };

       service.ClearCredentials = function () {
           $rootScope.globals = {};
           //$cookies.remove('globals');
           //$cookies.remove('session');
           $.jStorage.deleteKey('globals');
           $.jStorage.deleteKey('session');
           $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic ';
       };

       return service;
   }])
```

Here is my login Controller:

```
 .controller('loginCtrl',
 ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', 'AuthenticationService', '$routeParams', '$http',
 function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, AuthenticationService, $routeParams, $http) {

     $scope.login = function () {
         $scope.dataLoading = true;
         AuthenticationService.Login($scope.username, $scope.password, function (response) {
             responsedata = JSON.stringify(response);
             /* error handling*/
             if (responsedata.indexOf('error') > 0 || responsedata.indexOf('invalid') > 0) {
                 $scope.error = response.message;
                 $rootScope.className = 'error';
                 $rootScope.dataLoading = false;

             } else {
                 AuthenticationService.SetCredentials(response);
                 console.log('response: '+response);
                 $location.path('/home');
             };

         });
     };

     $scope.logout = function () {
         $rootScope.dataLoading = false;
         $rootScope.hideMe = true;
         $rootScope.PostDataResponse = '';
         $rootScope.ResponseDetails = '';
         //alert('logging out');
         AuthenticationService.ClearCredentials();
     };

     $scope.showMenuPanel = function () {
         $scope.hideMenuPanel = false;
     };

     $scope.doHideMenuPanel = function () {
         $scope.hideMenuPanel = true;
         $rootScope.PostDataResponse = '';
     };
 }])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually the Cordova app's [URL whitelisting settings](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/) that were causing the problem.